# match 3 words in a paragraph only using one regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a hard time trying to match multiple words completely using regex,

this is my text,

> Google is looking to dismantle the Spotify-Apple "duopoly" in music
>   distribution, overhauling its music service this week in the  fourth
>   attempt at convincing YouTube's billions of users to pay.
>
> Google is unveiling a new music subscription service on Tuesday, and
>   will promote it with YouTube's most expensive advertising  campaign.
>   The service, called YouTube Music, mimics the Spotify model: there
>   will be a free, ad-supported tier with more limited  functions, and a
>   $US10-a-month subscription without advertisements and with extra
>   functions.

I wanted to match 3 words `Spotify-Apple`, `US10` and `extra functions` and I want everything else to be ignored i tried

```
\bSpotify-Apple\b(.|\n)*?\bUS10\b(.|\n)*extra functions
```

it works to highlight all three phrases but also highlight all the text between them. how can i match just three words and ignore everything else?
i try to ignore it like using `^` too,

```
\bSpotify-Apple\b^(.|\n)*?\bUS10\b^(.|\n)*extra functions
```

Comment: What do you mean by highlight? What exactly is doing the highlighting?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8lcHe0/1

Comment: In your regex, replace `^(.|\n)*?` with just `|` and replace `^(.|\n)*` with just `|`

Comment: Why should you use regex while the thing you are searching for is a literal string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just

```
/\b(Spotify-Apple|US10|extra functions)\b/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1Z96tS/3

Answer (score 2):

```
\bSpotify-Apple\b|\bUS10\b|\bextra functions\b
```

This gives the exact three words you are trying to match.